# How i can edit action script of swf file

Tags: flash

Hi I am trying to edit action script (.as) of swf (flash movie) and I have also tried to edit days with JPEXS swf decompiler but I can't the size of my swf file is 15 MB. And the action script of the swf file is too long so that's why I can't able to edit this in JPEXS. does anyone have a solution for this please answer I am waiting.

Comment: **(1)** Explain _"...the ActionScript of the swf file is too long so that's why I can't able to edit this in JPEXS"_ because AS3 is just text. It can't be too long. Do you get any error message? **(2)** Try [using the command line](https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/features/commandline/) (run `cmd.exe`) to extract the AS code, then use any text editor to edit the code, then back to command line to re-compile as new SWF file.

Comment: Hii Vc.One Thanks for comment. This is the swf file which I want to edit please  check (https://www.mediafire.com/folder/6diodi1xz7k2c,eng3xbd5xb9u5s3) please also check the screenshot of swf file (https://www.mediafire.com/view/bac2yqoe66uny93/Capture.PNG/file) the action script of swf file which I want to edit and the total line of  actionscript  which I want to edit is   (112276). Please tell the solution of that